# XMLTree Parsing and Printing

Tags: python, xml, python-3.8

I'm starting to learn python3 and one of the things being discussed is XMLTree which I'm having a hard time grasping (most likely due to learning python concurrently)

What I am trying to do is output an easier to read version of my XML file.

The XML File: (there is no limit to the number of child customers - i've included two for example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customers>
     <customers>
          <number area_code="800" exch_code="225" sub_code="5288" />
          <address zip_code="90210" st_addr="9401 Sunset Blvd" />
          <nameText>First Choice</nameText>
     </customers>
     <customers>
          <number area_code="800" exch_code="867" sub_code="5309" /> 
          <address zip_code="60652" st_addr="5 Lake Shore Drive" />
          <nameText>Green Grass"</nameText>
     </customers>
</customers>
```

From what I understand, the [XML tree](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp) defines these lines as the following:

```
<root>
     <child>
          <element attribute...>
```

Where the first xml files 'customers' is the root, the second 'customers' is a child of 'customers', and 'number' (or address, or nameText) are elements.
With that being said, here is where I start to get confused.
If we take `<number area_code="800" exch_code="225" sub_code="5288" />`
This is an element with three attributes, area_code, exch_code, and sub_code but no text.
If we take `<nameText>Green Grass"</nameText>`
This is an element with no attributes, but does contain Text (Green Grass)
What I would like to see would be something like this:

```
First Choice 
|--> Phone Number: 800-225-5288
|--> Address: 9401 Sunset Blvd, Zip Code: 90210 
Green Grass
|--> Phone Number: 800-867-5309
|--> Address: 5 Lake Shore Drive, Zip Code: 60652
```

I dont have really any code to share but here it is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(my_files[0])
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.tag)
for child in root:
    print(child.tag,child.attrib)
```

Which provides the following output (line 1 being from print(root.tag) I believe)

```
customer
customer
{}
customer
{}
```

The questions I have after writing all this:
1 - Is my interpretation of the tree structure correct?
2 - How do you differentiate between attributes in ElementTree?
3 - How/what should I be considerate of in terms of the attributes, tags, and the rest of this file when trying to make the desired output? I might be overthinking how much more complex having XML in the mix is making this scenario so I am struggling to figure out how to do something similar to get the output I saw here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces but my xml lacks namespaces.

I'm still trying to learn, so any additional explanation is sincerely appreciated!

Resources that I've been trying to read through to understand all this:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html# (When I'm looking through this, I'm going off the assumption that when they are calling something an attribute, its not something unique to ElementTree but the same attribute as defined in the next link)
- https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp (however I havent seen anything yet about multiple attributes)
- https://www.edureka.co/blog/python-xml-parser-tutorial/ (This page has been a great help breaking things down step by step so I have been able to follow along)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 - Is my interpretation of the tree structure correct?

The ElementTree parser only knows about two entities: elements and
attributes. So when you say:

> From what I understand, the XML tree defines these lines as the following:
>
> ```
> <root>
>      <child>
>           <element attribute...>
> ```

I'm a little confused. Your XML document -- or any other XML document
-- is just an element that may have zero or more attributes and may
have zero or more children...and so forth all the way down.

> 2 - How do you differentiate between attributes in ElementTree?

It's not clear what you mean by "differentiate" here; you can ask for
elements by name. For example, the following code prints out the
`areacode` attribute of all `<number>` elements:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> doc = ET.parse(open('data.xml'))
>>> doc.findall('.//number')
[<Element number at 0x7fdb8981e640>, <Element number at 0x7fdb8981e680>]
>>> for x in root.findall('.//number'):
...     print(x.get('area_code'))
...
800
800
```

If you'd like, you can get all of the attributes of an element as a Python
dictionary:

```
>>> number = doc.find('customers/number')
>>> attrs = dict(number.items())
>>> attrs
{'area_code': '800', 'exch_code': '225', 'sub_code': '5288'}
```

> 3 - How/what should I be considerate of in terms of the attributes, tags, and the rest of this file when trying to make the desired output?

That code seems to have mostly what you're looking for. As you say,
you're not using namespaces, so you don't need to qualify element
names with namespace names...that is, you can write `number` instead
of `{some/name/space}number`.

That gives us something like:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


with open('data.xml') as fd:
    doc = ET.parse(fd)


for customer in doc.findall('customers'):
    name = customer.find('nameText')
    number = customer.find('number')
    address = customer.find('address')
    print(name.text)
    print('|--> Address: {}, Zip Code: {}'.format(
        address.get('st_addr'), address.get('zip_code')))
    print('|--> Phone number: {}-{}-{}'.format(
        number.get('area_code'), number.get('exch_code'), number.get('sub_code')))
```

Given your sample input, this produces:

```
First Choice
|--> Address: 9401 Sunset Blvd, Zip Code: 90210
|--> Phone number: 800-225-5288
Green Grass"
|--> Address: 5 Lake Shore Drive, Zip Code: 60652
|--> Phone number: 800-867-5309
```

Comment: Hi larsks and thank you for your assistance!  
Your answer for Q1 makes much more sense to me and shows that I was thinking of the "relationship" between elements and not that they were elements themselves.    
Your answer for Q2 was spot on and very informative.   
Your answer for Q3 and the subsequent code examples not only work flawlessly but show me that this scenario was actually much simpler than how I was imagining it. 

I cannot thank you enough for explaining this so clearly and taking me through it step by step.